# How to display tQuery.World in a canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, tquery

i think it is as simple as it sounds, but i just can't find anything that can help me.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var world  = tQuery.createWorld().boilerplate();
    world.start();
```

what should i do, to display it in the canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass a renderer

```
var world  = tQuery.createWorld({
    renderer: new THREE.CanvasRenderer({
        canvas : canvas
    })
}).boilerplate();
```

something like that